# Allow iframe to execute cordova command

Tags: cordova, iframe

Currenlty I'm embedding on online site within a cordova app; my config.xml is the following:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

and my index.html have the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; 
style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

now I need to execute a codova command (of the app) from the inner site, I'm using the following code:

```
window.parent.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {},
function (error) {});
```

but it's (correctly) failing with a:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "file://".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the
>   frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.

How can I allow this kind of interaction from an external site to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of CORS and sandbox iframe is definetily not the correct way to handle this kind of communication.

In Cordova there is a plugin called [`InAppBrowser`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/); we can install it:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

and it allow us to interact with a browser windows with a kind of messagging using `executeScript` method:

```
var myRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://<site>', '_blank', 'location=no');

myRef.executeScript({ code: "localStorage.setItem( 'demo', '' );" });
```